# how to write generic method for expand capacity of array?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want write a generic method to expand the capacity of the array that with specific type. The function signature may like this(not have to), the parameter "growth" means the number of growing capacity.

***public static  T[]  expandCapacity(T[] array, int growth)***

The example: Integer[] testArray = new Integer[5];
             testArray = expandCapacity(testArray,5);

after executed this function, the testArray.length should be 10.

Comment: Okay, so go and write it?

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing this instead of using one of the `List` types, like `ArrayList`?

Comment: we know that List interface like "ArrayList" use Object array to store data and "ArrayList" can be resized, so I want to write an demo to implement this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a generic type `T` with a `static` method you must specify it with a `<T>`. Then you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) which (per the Javadoc) *copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length.*

```
public static <T> T[] expandCapacity(T[] array, int growth) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + growth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the length of the original array, which means the return array of `expandCapacity` is the same reference as the parameter `array`, it's impossible because an array has a fixed length after its initialization.

If the return array isn't the same reference, just create a new array with the new size inside the method and copy the data from the source array, but I'm afraid it's not what you want.

I suggest you look into [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface as well as its implementations like [`ArrayList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) whose size can be changed.